# Checkbox options like Gmail in Angular 11

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular11

I am trying to do a checkbox with options like Gmail

[image: Option Image]

I wrote functions to select all and deselect all. But I don't know how to bind them.

.ts

```
  checkedRow = false;
  checkedAll = false;

  AllSelectedHandler(checked: boolean, book){
      // this is done to select all and deselect all
   }
```

.html

```
 <nb-checkbox [value]= "books" [checked]="checkedAll" (checkedChange)="AllSelectedHandler($event, books)" ></nb-checkbox>  //this is worked

 <select name="delete-option" id="delete-option" ><i class="nb-arrow-dropdown fa-1x"></i> 
          <option  value="all" >All</option>
           <option value="none" > None</option>
 </select>
```

I need how to bind inside the  tag

Comment: https://ngninja.com/posts/angular-gmail-multi-select-control

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597722/gmail-like-select-all-checkbox